# Print the output in my desired format using nested serializers?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to send messages using django-rest framework.I have created serializers for both user and message.I am using django default user model for storing user's details.

I am pasting my model and serializers here:

```
class MessageModel(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')
```

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['id','username','email']


class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = MessageModel
        fields = ['id','message', 'created_at', 'updated_at','user','created_by']
```

View :

```
class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = MessageModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

After creating message,I am getting response like below:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "message": "Lorem ipsum",
    "created_at": "2022-11-07T09:21:19.492219Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-11-07T09:21:19.492237Z",
    "user": 2
}
```

but my output should looks like in below format,everytime when a new message is created :

```
{
  "id": 102,
  "message": "Lorem ipsum",
  "created_at": "created time in UTC",
  "updated_at": "last updated time in UTC",
  "created_by": {
  "id": 3,
    "username": "testuser",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    }
}
```

In case of any error, return the error message.

Comment: There is no `created_by` field in `MessageModel` then how?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field is `user`, not `created_by`, so:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MessageModel
        fields = ['id', 'message', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'user']
```

or you can specify `user` as source:

```
class MessageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True, source='user')

    class Meta:
        model = MessageModel
        fields = ['id', 'message', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by']
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`MessageModel`</s> to `Message`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `MessageModel`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`user`</s> relation to `messages`.

Comment: Hii Willem, I am getting "    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: Message_messagemodel.user_id" .  this error message.

Comment: @RatnambarGupta: likely you are making a POST request to *create* a message object, and since you used `readonly=True`, it thus has no `user` field filled in, hence the error

Comment: Hey @Willem ,I am giving input in this format :{
    "message":"Hii this is testing",
    "user": 2
}           but getting the above error.

Comment: How can I fix that error?